# Packaging a Java/JNI-wrapped C++ library (with a .so dependency) for distribution

Tags: android, build

I have the following structure:

1. **Android (Java) *testApp*/consumer**, that demonstrates/uses:

   2. **Java/JNI *wrapper***, that wraps:

      3. **C++ *engine***, that has a dependency upon a:

         4. ***FFT.so* library** (which I've compiled myself) 
            There is the added complication that I have a separate .so for each architecture {arm7, arm8, x86, x86_64}

I've got all of the components working in isolation.

I'm planning to sell the engine to Android developers. The engine itself has to be binary/closed-source. The rest of it doesn't matter.

The important thing is to optimise the experience of the developer in integrating the engine.

My question is this: ***What's the cleanest structure?***

First off, I need to ship:
 - **engine.so**
 - **fft.so**

But now how to design **wrapper** so as to minimise the effort of dropping it into a third-party app?

Can I make it a library module? Pretty sure I read yesterday that there is an issue with /jniLibs/. i.e. you can drop a multi-arch .so into an app module by just putting the files in a /jniLibs/ folder, but you can't do this with a *library* module.

So I think I can make it a library module, maybe even compile it to a .so. But the consumer is going to need to link to /jniLibs/$ARCH/libfft.so and engine.so and wrapper.so.

It feels like there must be some standard way to package something like this, but I lack the experience and perspective.

Comment: I use library modules with C++ dependencies all the time, it works fine across multiple architectures (at least x86 simulators and ARM devices).  The big thing for me as a developer is I want everything wrapped in Java so I don't need to do more than call 1 initialization function, and you do all the loading of .so files and the like.

Comment: Problem for me is I want one C++ library to access functions in another C++ library. So I don't think I want to route that through Java.

Comment: You don't need to.  Have that C++ library load its own dependencies.   I don't care what your library does under the hood, so long as I only need to make one call to initialize it.